# Doesn't this Node / Express code create two servers?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, http

I am beginning development with Node & Express. I have managed to create a few apps, including a portal to a friend's company. Now I want to try Socket.io and WebRTC and while studying for a future app, I noticed they both use something similar to the following code:

```
const express = require('express')

const app = express()
const server = require('http').createServer(app)
const port = process.env.PORT || 3000

// just to test the server
app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  res.status(200).send('Working')
})

server.listen(port, () => {
  console.log(`Server running on port: ${port}`)
})
```

My questions are:

Doesn't this code create **TWO** servers? I mean, if Express can handle the requests and the responses, why do I need to use the 'http' module?

Thank you in advance to those willing to teach a newbie without judgement.

Comment: Is only one server but ready for http protocol.

Comment: You can simply omit `const server = require('http').createServer(app)` and do `app.listen(port.....` You are not technically creating 2 servers but you are using Node's native `createServer` - something express does for you anyway...

Comment: No, `app` is not a server. It doesn't listen for connections on a port.

Comment: @Georges - good question, and SakoBu gave an excellent answer.  You *may* call either `app.listen(...)` or `server.listen(...)`.  In both cases, you'd be using Express ... which, in turn, relies on Node's native `createServer()`.

Comment: Like the others, you are not creating two servers. You actually running the server whenever you call the `listen()` method. When you are creating a `http` server with express settings manually, you just extracting all the settings and options that the `.createServer(app)` returns. In `express` source code, whenever you call the express application object `listen` method, it just returns the `createServer().listen()` method to you which in this case we call it "abstraction" for sake of being a framework.

Comment: Thank you,  guys. It makes sense and I had not used the 'http' modules so far. I simply create my routes and use _app.listen()_.

But, like I asked @jfriend00, why do Socket.io and other libraries like PeerJS suggest this setting, using the 'http' module? Isn't the server automatically created with _app.listen_ capable of handling connections to ports other than that specified (e.g. 3000)?

Is that why I need to pass another server to Socket.io, 'simple-peer' etc?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Doesn't this code create TWO servers?

No, the code you show only creates one http server.

Here's an annotated version of your code that explains what each line does:

```
// load the express module
const express = require('express')

// create an Express app object
const app = express()

// create an http server object and pass it the Express app object as a request handler
// this is a server object, but is not yet a running server
const server = require('http').createServer(app)

// decide what port we're going to use for the http server
const port = process.env.PORT || 3000

// create one Express route handler on the Express app object
app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  res.status(200).send('Working')
})

// start up the server on the desired port so it is now actually running
// and log to the console when the server has finished starting up and is ready
// for incoming http requests
server.listen(port, () => {
  console.log(`Server running on port: ${port}`)
})
```

> I mean, if Express can handle the requests and the responses, why do I need to use the 'http' module?

Express is a framework for handling incoming http requests.  Express itself does not contain any http server code and the `app` object in your code is not a server itself.  It is an object that is used to coordinate and organize request handlers for incoming http requests.  The incoming http requests come from an http server that must be created separately from Express.

Some code somewhere has to create an http server and then connect your Express app object with it.  There are multiple ways to create the http server that you're going to use with Express.  Your code using `http.createServer(app)` followed by `server.listen()` shows one such way to do that.

---

There are other ways to create the http server to use with Express.  For example, the `app.listen()` method can create an http server and automatically bind the `app` object to it.

If you look at the [source code for `app.listen()`](https://github.com/expressjs/express/blob/master/lib/application.js#L615), you see this:

```
app.listen = function listen() {
  var server = http.createServer(this);
  return server.listen.apply(server, arguments);
};
```

All it does is create an http server with the `app` object as a listener and then call `.listen()` on that new server.  This is essentially the same thing you're doing yourself with `http.createServer(app)` and then `server.listen(...)`.

But, in all cases here some code somewhere is using `http.createServer(...)` to create a server object and then `server.listen(port)` to start it.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. So, what I understand from your reply is that I **do not** really need the 'http' module, which makes total sense since I have been creating apps without it so far.

Comment: But, why do Socket.io and other libraries like PeerJS suggest this setting, using the 'http' module? Isn't the server automatically created with _app.listen_ capable of handling connections to ports other than that specified (e.g. 3000)?

Is that why I need to pass another server to Socket.io, 'simple-peer' etc?

Comment: @Georges - You'd have to show me some specific code that I could answer a specific question about.  socket.io needs an http server in order to work so again, someone has to create an http server.  The socket.io library (like the Express library) can create it's own http server or it can use an existing http server that you've already created (it can share your regular web server).  A given server works on ONE port and only one port.  If you want servers listening on more than one port, you create a separate server instance for each port.

Answer (score -3):

This should work for you. You don't need the line you mentioned.

```
const express = require('express')

const app = express()
const port = process.env.PORT || 3000

// just to test the server
app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  res.status(200).send('Working')
})

app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log(`Server running on port: ${port}`)
})
```

Comment: Some explanation would make for a better answer.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to answer, @callmebeewee, but the question goes beyond the deletion of the line. I have been using Express like you mentioned from the beginning. But Socket.io and many other libraries/modules show that line (or similar) in their examples. I wonder if it has to do with the fact they are to sending actual http requests...